# Spring relationship get child id without load sub class

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How to get DEPARTMENT_ID of the base class without loading sub-class in Spring boot JPA

For example we have a base model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TM_POSITIONS")
public class PositionEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PositionsSequence", sequenceName = "TM_POSITIONS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PositionsSequence")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private DepartmentModel department;
...
```

So, how to just get DEPARTMENT_ID without bundle it and load another object. In some cases, I need to get related Model and in some cases, I need to get just DEPARTMENT_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. In the EAGER way the sub-class will always be loaded.

If you set the fetch type lazy, you can reach the sub-class's id (primary-key) field without extra db queries.

So if you write `position.getDepartment().getId()` you will get the id and it won't cost anything.

Keep in mind, that other method calls on the sub-class will be load it from the database, e.g.: toString, equals, or getName() /if there is such a method/.

In the case you need the sub-class for some other functionalities, you should write another query in your reposiroty which will fetch the sub-class too.

```
@Query("SELECT pos FROM Position LEFT JOIN FETCH pos.department")
```

With `JOIN FETCH` Spring Data JPA will generate a single query which will join the two table, so you can avoid the [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue) problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a responseDTO class and a mapper class for that.

```
@ApiModel
public class positionEntityResponseDTO{

private long id;
private long departmentId;

//getter & setter

}
```

And the mapper class look like

```
 @Service
    public class ResponseMapper{
     public positionEntityResponseDTO map (PositionEntity entity){
       positionEntityResponseDTO response = new positionEntityResponseDTO();
        response.setId(entity.getId);
        response.setDepartmentId(entity.getDepartment.getId();
        return response;

    }

    }
```

now suppose somewhere you write

```
@Autowired
private ResponseMapper mapper;
positionEntityResponseDTO response= mapper.map(repository.save(entity));
```

now you can pass only `DEPARTMENT_ID` by `response` object. hope this works for you.